# How can I reset input data on the modal in vue.js 2?

Tags: modal-dialog, vue.js, image-uploading, vuejs2, vue-component

My Vue component to display a modal is like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ...
                    <a href="javascript:">
                        <img v-if="image == ''" :src="'https://myshop.co.id/img/no-image.jpg'" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        <img v-else :src="image" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                    </a>
                    ...
                    <input type="file" v-on:change="changeImage">
                ...          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        ...
        data() {
            return {
                image: '',
                ...
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeImage($event) {
                const selectedImage = $event.target.files[0]
                const form = new FormData();
                form.append('file', selectedImage);
                // define the done handler
                const onDone = (data) => {
                    if (!$.trim(data)) {   
                        alert('No response');
                    }
                    else {   
                        var files = $event.target.files || $event.dataTransfer.files
                        if (!files.length)
                            return;
                        this.createImage(files[0])
                        this.imageChanged = data
                        this.disabled = 0
                    }

                }
                // define th post options
                const options = {
                    url: window.Laravel.baseUrl+'/product/addImage',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: form,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
                    contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
                }
                // submit the image
                $.ajax(options).done(onDone);
            },
            createImage(file) {
                var image = new Image()
                var reader = new FileReader()
                var vm = this
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    vm.image = e.target.result
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file)
            },
        } 
    }
</script>
```

When the modal shows, it will display a file input.

If I upload image using the file input, it will display that image in the HTML.

When I close the modal and re-open it, the image is still displayed.

I want to reset the input data in the modal so that when I open the modal again, the image will disappear.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `this.image=''` when the modal closes.

In bootstrap you can do this automatically when the modal closes by listening to the `hidden.bs.modal` event. You can clear file inputs by setting their value to `null`.

Add a `ref` attribute to your modal

```
<div ref="modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
...
<input ref="imageInput" type="file" v-on:change="changeImage">
```

And add code to listen to the event.

```
mounted(){
    $(this.$refs.modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
        this.image = ''
        this.$refs.imageInput.value = null
    })
}
```

Comment: Is this available without using jQuery?

Comment: @Maleta No, this version of bootstrap emits the event using jQuery.